# Different ways of initializing an object with default constructor in C++

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, default-constructor

```
struct A 
{
 int a;
 std::string str;
};

A a;// 1
A a{};// 2
A a = {};// 3
A a = A();// 4
```

There seems to be all options. In case 1 and 4 `a` will be uninitialized, in 2 and 3 `a` will be initialized with zero and they both are same and just the matter of style or there is some difference? 4 supposed to first create a temporary object and then assign it to an `a`, but it will happen only if I will turn off comliler's optimization completely, right?

Comment: In case 4 `a` and `a.a` are both initialized

Answer (score 4):

For all the cases the data member `str` is always default-initialized by the default constructor of `std::string`. Due to the different initialization styles, the data member `a` might be initialized to `0` or indeterminate value. In details,

1. The 1st one is [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), as the result `a.a` is initialized to indeterminate value (or gets zero-initialized to `0` if `a` is static or thread-local object), `a.str` is initialized by its default constructor.
2. The 2nd one is [direct-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is performed, as the result `a.a` is [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) ([zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)) to `0`, `a.str` is initialized by its default constructor.
3. The 3rd one is [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and aggregate initialization is performed, as the result `a.a` is value-initialized (zero-initialized) to `0`, `a.str` is initialized by its default constructor.
4. In concept the 4th one is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), `a` is copy-initialized from `A()` (value-initialized temporary `A`). Because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17 it's mandatory) `a` might be value-initialized directly, as the result (which doesn't get changed by copy elision) `a.a` is zero-initialized to `0`, `a.str` is initialized by its default constructor.

Comment: `a`'s default constructor is not called in cases 2,3 which are aggregate initialization

Comment: @M.M I don't consider that because I think `A` is non an aggregate bcecause it has a non-aggregate member `str`, it seems wrong...

Comment: The meaning of "aggregate" is defined by [dcl.init.aggr], there is no prohibition of subobjects being non-aggregate

Comment: @M.M Thanks for pointing that, my misunderstanding.

Comment: @M.M what do you mean that "default constructor is not called"? In this case, where default constructor is added by compiler? As when I added to the class default constructor it is called in all cases.

Comment: @DoehJohn my comment refers only to the code in the question